# UIScrollView inside paged UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have UIScrollView (inner - UICollectionView to be honest) in VC which is in paged UIScrollView (outer). Both are horizontal.
When I scroll inner to edge (either left or right side) it starts passing touches to outer scroll and outer scroll starts scrolling.
How to avoid that kind of behaviour? I want outer scroll to not react on touches in inner scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an `UIView` under the outer `UIScrollView`, and set it to `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`

Comment: How it may prevent passing dragging event from inner scroll to outer scroll?

Comment: if it was set to userInteractionEnabled = NO; then it will not pass the dragging events

Comment: The problem is that I'm touching directly inner scrollView and when I drag (I'm not releasing finger) to its content end it starts passing touches to outer scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this:
Subclass UIScrollView - this will be your outer scrollView
now the method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIView *touchedView = gestureRecognizer.view;
    CGPoint loc = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:touchedView];
    UIView* subview = [touchedView hitTest:loc withEvent:nil];

    if([[subview nextResponder] isKindOfClass:[MyInnerScrollVC class]]) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

and thats it